# Blockchain Websocket API with Python gets Bad Request 400

Tags: api, websocket, cryptography, blockchain

I am trying to establish a websocket to blockchain over blockchain exchange api, but I get a response like `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.

Code example taken from https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client

CODE I

```py
import websocket
from websocket import create_connection

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    msg = '{"token": "", "action": "subscribe", "channel": "auth"}'
    ws.send(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # options = {'origin': 'https://exchange.blockchain.com'}
    url = "wss://ws.prod.blockchain.info/mercury-gateway/v1/ws"
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

```
--- request header ---
GET /mercury-gateway/v1/ws HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: ws.prod.blockchain.info
Origin: http://ws.prod.blockchain.info
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ldRVrsrxBUnvokDHvzNICw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

```
--- response header ---
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2021 23:20:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 70
X-Cache-Status: 9b46f4091784da7cbae64c3e66446707
X-Blockchain-Language: en
X-Blockchain-Language-ID: 0:0:0 (en:en:en)
X-Request-ID: 5ef71341f43f1d9ec5d37c25164676dc
X-Original-Host: ws.prod.blockchain.info
X-Blockchain-Server: BlockchainFE/1.0
X-Blockchain-CP-F: j1vn 0.012 - 5ef71341f43f1d9ec5d37c25164676dc
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: clear
Connection: close
```

I tried with and without the `options` dictionary, but without any success.

Although that code works, but I need the event methods on_message, on_error, on_close and on_open.

Either there is a way to get those events working for CODE II or there is a way to establish the websocket connection for CODE I.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you!

CODE II

```py
from websocket import create_connection
options = {}
options['origin'] = 'https://exchange.blockchain.com'
url = "wss://ws.prod.blockchain.info/mercury-gateway/v1/ws"
ws = create_connection(url, **options)
print(ws.sock_opt)
msg = '{"token": "", "action": "subscribe", "channel": "auth"}'
ws.send(msg)
result = ws.recv()
print(result)
msg = '{"action": "subscribe", "channel": "balances"}'
ws.send(msg)
result = ws.recv()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is, setting the origin-Header to the right value, like this:

```
import websocket

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time


def on_message(ws, message):
    print("MSG:", message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print("### error ###")
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    msg = '{"action": "subscribe", "channel": "prices", "symbol": "BTC-EUR", "granularity": "60" }'
    ws.send(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "wss://ws.prod.blockchain.info/mercury-gateway/v1/ws"
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    options = {'origin': 'https://exchange.blockchain.com'}
    ws.run_forever(origin=options['origin'])
```